# What is the difference bewteen "features" and "covariates" in the recent Syntetic Control (SC) literature?

Tags: econometrics, weighted-regression, synthetic-controls

I am reading Cattaneo, Feng & Titiunik (2021)'s JASA paper, "Prediction Intervals for Synthetic Control Methods" ([here ungated](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.07120)) and have encountered a development of SC that I don't understand much.

Instead of building the SC using an outcome variable and a set of covariates, they generalise to multiple (primary + secondary) outcomes and call the secondary outcomes features. They call these secondary outcomes "features". Each outcome can then have covariates, which need to be common across outcomes.

In this context, the difference between "features" and "covariates" is very blurred to me, and features seem more useful as they can vary over time, while covariates cannot. What is the specific role of features in building the SC, and how is it different from the one of covariates?

I found the following passage of the paper confusing in the above sense:

> This outcomes-only version of the SC method, however, cannot guarantee that the resulting SC unit will be similar to the treated unit in any characteristics other than the (pre-treatment) outcome. In some applications, this feature may be undesirable, as researchers may have access to additional characteristics such as baseline covariates or secondary outcomes and may want to also ensure that the SC approximates the treated unit in terms of these additional characteristics. The SC framework can handle this case by including additional equations for these additional characteristics and minimizing the combined loss. In this case, letting $l=1,2, \ldots, M$ index the variables that will be "matched" to produce the weights, the minimization problem above can be generalized as follows:
> $$
> \left(\widehat{\mathbf{w}}^{\prime}, \widehat{\mathbf{r}}\right)^{\prime} \in \underset{\mathbf{w} \in \mathcal{W}, \mathbf{r} \in \mathcal{R}}{\arg \min } \sum_{l=1}^M \sum_{t=1}^{T_0} v_{t, l}\left(Y_{1 t, l}-Y_{2 t, l} w_2-\cdots-Y_{(N+1) t, l} w_{N+1}-r_l\right)^2,
> $$
> where $\widehat{\mathbf{r}}=\left(\widehat{r}_1, \ldots, \widehat{r}_M\right)^{\prime}$ and $\left\{v_{t, l}\right\}_{1 \leq t \leq T_0, 1 \leq l \leq M}$ are positive constants reflecting the relative importance of different equations and periods.